# ng-change not working with dropdown list

Tags: angularjs-directive

In the code `ng-change` is not working it gives an error. Why? I need to execute the method `show()` every time the selected value changes. Also the below `div` tag should be visible only after selection of a valid list value.

```html
 <div class="form-group">
 <label>SOURCE</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="ddlFirst" ngmodel="ddlSource" ng-change="show()">
 <option value="null" ng-selected="true">--Select Sprint--</option>
 <option  ng-repeat="s in AllS" value="{{s.Id}}">{{s.Name}}</option>
 </select>
 </div>

//this div should be visible only when a valid list value is selected.s.id will hv +ve value on valid list value selection

<div ng-show="ddlSource==isNumber()">
 <label> hiiiiii</label>
</div>


result is:

Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngModel', required by directive 'ngChange', can't be found!
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$compile/ctreq?p0=ngModel&p1=ngChange
    at REGEX_STRING_REGEXP (angular.js:64)
    at getControllers (angular.js:7584)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7773)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7118)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7121)
    at nodeLinkFn (angular.js:7764)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7118)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7121)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7121)
    at compositeLinkFn (angular.js:7121)
```

Comment: check my updated plunker in my answer . let me know if it solves your problem .

Answer (score 3):

ng-change require ng-model directive . In your code
 `<select class="form-control" name="ddlFirst" ngmodel="ddlSource" ng-change="show()">`

It should be rather ng-model instead of ngmodel .

Here is [Plunker Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/hu3KNVv4U3XGmFrb0ZU9?).

I have created a sample from your code which detect the change in dropdown.

```
<div ng-controller='CalcCtrl'>
<label>SOURCE</label>
 <select class="form-control" name="ddlFirst" ng-model="ddlSource" ng-change="show()">

 <option  ng-repeat="s in AllS" value="{{s.Id}}">{{s.Name}}</option>
 </select>
 </div>
```

My jsfile looks like this.

```
 var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('CalcCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.AllS=[{Name:"ram",Id:'1'},{Name:"shyam",Id:'2'}];
    $scope.show = function(){alert("changed");}
});
```

I hope this would solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Btw just a pro tip whenever you see this Camel casing error complaining about directive by the angularjs errors log. You should automatically know that you've missed something with an `-`, in this case you have confused `ng-model` for `ngmodel`. So what happens is `ngChange` is expecting `ng-model` values from the directive but instead gets `ngmodel` which you have used. so the `Controller 'ngModel'` error.

Just so that you know `ng-model` is converted by angular under the hood to `ngModel`.

@jigs answer is right I am just trying to give more info.